# Перемещение контента Scroll View через код

Tags: c#, unity3d

**Здравствуйте, я новичок в Unity**

Делаю приложение-справочник на Андроид. В приложении много текста и картинок, поэтому использую `Scroll View`. Захотелось сделать как в книгах алфавитный указатель (нажимаешь на текст, он переносит тебя в скролл-баре в нужное место).
Вопрос - как это реализовать как можно проще?

Comment: Прикладные приложения лучше реализовать под более подходящими для этой задачи фреймворками, например для мобильников Xamarin Forms. В Unity UI, мягко говоря, слабоват для этого.

Comment: Извините, не могли бы Вы объяснить поподробнее про фреймворки.

Comment: Не мог бы, термин "фреймворк" вы сами легко способны расшифровать. Суть моего послания в том, что если нужно вскопать грядку - берите лопату, а то граблями это делать будет не очень удобно.

Comment: Если интересует решение именно под Unity, то стоит добавить побольше подробностей. Сейчас не очень понятно, что вы хотите.

Comment: Unity3d действительно не инструмент для таких задач, а что касается `ScrollView, что бы не возникало таких вопросов, есть [документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.ScrollView.html).